# Why winform panel only updates when mouseover or mouseclick?

Tags: .net, linux, winforms, mono, backcolor

I created a test program that is supposed to change backcolor of a panel back and forth repeatedly under linux (PCLinuxOS), but it doesn't really work very well. Either it only updates the panels' backcolor only when you click on something or mouseover a winform then it stops or the program crashes altogether after running for little while.

Here is how the winform looks with 2 panels, a button and a timer:

[image]

Here is the code behind it:

```
namespace TestIndicator;

interface

uses
  System.Drawing,
  System.Collections,
  System.Collections.Generic,
  System.Windows.Forms,
  System.ComponentModel;

type
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for MainForm.
  /// </summary>
  MainForm = partial class(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
  private
    method d_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
    method timer1_Tick(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
  protected
    method Dispose(disposing: Boolean); override;
  public
    constructor;
  end;

var
    TurnOnRx, TurnOnTx:Boolean;

implementation

{$REGION Construction and Disposition}
constructor MainForm;
begin
  //
  // Required for Windows Form Designer support
  //
  InitializeComponent();

  //
  // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
  //
  TurnOnRx := true;
  TurnOnTx := true;
end;

method MainForm.Dispose(disposing: Boolean);
begin
  if disposing then begin
    if assigned(components) then
      components.Dispose();

    //
    // TODO: Add custom disposition code here
    //
  end;
  inherited Dispose(disposing);
end;
{$ENDREGION}

method MainForm.d_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
    timer1.Enabled := not timer1.Enabled;  
end;

method MainForm.timer1_Tick(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
    if TurnOnTx then
    begin
        TurnOnTx:=false;
        TxLight.BackColor := Color.Red;
    end
    else
    begin
        TurnOnTx:=true;
        TxLight.BackColor := Color.black;
    end;

    if TurnOnRx then
    begin
        TurnOnRx := false;
        RxLight.BackColor := Color.Lime;
    end
    else
    begin
        TurnOnRx := true;
        RxLight.BackColor := Color.Black;
    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It works only when clicking the form because you're enabling the timer only under click handler. If you want the panels to straight away blink then enable (or start) the timer in the constructor. And what is the error you get on mouse over? I see no mouse-over handler anywhere anyway..

Comment: @nawfal, I meant once the timer is started or enabled by clicking on the button, the panel backcolor doesn't update but only when you move your mouse pointer over a button and/or click on the button or winform toolbar even though timer is enabled. Other times it just sits there does nothing. However, I can take this same program and run it on windows it works as expected.

Comment: However, I can take this same program and run it on windows it works as expected. Yes, I don't have any mouse over event. The program is acting like it is only sending the WM_Paint message flag to repaint or refresh when you only does something to the winform.

Comment: I have no idea why it is so then. I thought it could be some bug in code.

Comment: Try adding `RxLight.Invalidate()` to the end of `timer1_Tick()`, that tells the drawing component that the control needs to be redrawn. Windows' WinForms implementation does that automatically, maybe Mono's does not?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast, I already tried that. It doesn't work as well. First of all, my timer is set for 100 milliseconds interval and with Invalidate method, the panels are only updated once 2 or 3 seconds. As described above, as soon as I move my mouse pointer over the winform or click on it and hold it, the panels' backcolor blinks a lot faster as expected. I also tried Refresh method as well it does work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe timer interval is too short and colors change too fast?

```
namespace TestIndicator;
interface
uses
  System.Drawing,
  System.Collections,
  System.Collections.Generic,
  System.Windows.Forms,  
  System.ComponentModel;

type
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for MainForm.
  /// </summary>
  MainForm = partial class(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
  private
    method d_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
    method timer1_Tick(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
  protected
    method Dispose(disposing: Boolean); override;
  public
    constructor;
  end;

var
    TurnOnRx, TurnOnTx:Boolean;

implementation

{$REGION Construction and Disposition}
constructor MainForm;
begin
  //
  // Required for Windows Form Designer support
  //
  InitializeComponent();

  //
  // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
  //
  TurnOnRx := true;
  TurnOnTx := true;

  timer1.Inverval := 1000; 
end;

method MainForm.Dispose(disposing: Boolean);
begin
  if disposing then begin
    if assigned(components) then
      components.Dispose();

    //
    // TODO: Add custom disposition code here
    //
  end;
  inherited Dispose(disposing);
end;
{$ENDREGION}

method MainForm.d_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
    timer1.Enabled := not timer1.Enabled;  
end;

method MainForm.timer1_Tick(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
    if TurnOnTx then
    begin
        TurnOnTx:=false;
        TxLight.BackColor := Color.Red;
    end
    else
    begin
        TurnOnTx:=true;
        TxLight.BackColor := Color.black;
    end;

    if TurnOnRx then
    begin
        TurnOnRx := false;
        RxLight.BackColor := Color.Lime;
    end
    else
    begin
        TurnOnRx := true;
        RxLight.BackColor := Color.Black;
    end;

    TxLight.Refresh();
    RxLight.Refresh();

    Application.DoEvents();
end;

end.
```